# Having issues Creating a Child Theme in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress

Hello I followed the steps on:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

and still no luck, the theme activates fine but the parent theme still remains fully active.

Style.css:
[image]

functions.php:
[image]

File Location & WP Editor:
[image]
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated thank you. Again the child theme does not seem to overwrite the parent theme dalton.

Comment: What do you mean when you say 'the parent theme remains fully active'? At the moment your child theme CSS has no actual declarations in it, and you're only enqueuing the parent theme stylesheet.

Comment: I don't know to be honest, I have no css yes. My child theme is activated but when i load http//:localhost/wordpress/ it still displays the parent's style.css

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to enqueue the parent theme's stylesheet in your child theme CSS - that should already be enqueued (and you may find, if you look in the source, that you've simply got two copies of the parent theme stylesheet in place).

Enqueue your child theme stylesheet like so:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_the_enqueue_styles', 12); // Give this a lower priority so that it should be enqueued after the parent theme

function my_the_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
```

...then, in your child theme CSS, add something obvious like:

```
body {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

...and you should see that the child theme stylesheet is loaded alongside your parent theme elements.

It's worth noting that `get_template_directory_uri()` will always refer to the parent theme, whereas `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` will always refer to the currently-active child theme. If there is no child/parent theme and you're using a regular standalone theme, you can use these commands interchangeably.

Comment: Hi indextwo, thank you for the feedback. I made the appropriate changes but it did not solve this, and I did not see any child theme stylesheet alongside my parent theme. My site's homepage address is http://localhost/wordpress/ and the theme uri is: http://localhost/wordpress/dalton-child

Comment: `localhost` refers to your own machine (the same as `127.0.0.1`), so I won't be able to view that, I'm afraid. When you look at the source, what stylesheets are being enqueued?

Comment: By source, do you mean the parent's style.css file?

Comment: No, I mean in your browser, view the source code of the page. For example, in Firefox: Tools->Web Developer->Page Source. You want to check the source code for the CSS files that are enqueued.

Comment: ok there were many but I found these two: <link rel="stylesheet" id="child-style-css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/dalton-child/style.css?ver=4.5.3" type="text/css" media="all">              and           <link rel="stylesheet" id="main-styles-css" href="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/dalton/css/style.css?ver=4.5.3" type="text/css" media="all">

Comment: In that case, it's working. `/dalton-child/style.css?ver=4.5.3` is being enqueued. Now you just need to add some styles to it.

Comment: But it isn't displaying a blank page like in all the tutorials I have seen, it is showing the formatted style.css from the parent theme still. Any ideas why?

Comment: That's because a child theme is exactly what it sounds like: it is a *child* of the parent theme. As such, it adopts **all** of the styles and templates. You child theme's CSS doesn't _overwrite_ the parent CSS; it _compliments_ it (for example, if you want all the same styling but a different font color, you add just the `font-color` line in your child theme CSS). If you want to completely remove the parent stylesheet, you'll want to *dequeue* it in your child's functions.php: `wp_dequeue_style('main-styles');` (assuming `main-styles` is the parent stylesheet's ID).

Comment: Ah ok i see, thank you for the clarification. My header is currently set to: #header {background-color: #ffffff;} and I added #header {background-color: rgba(0,180,245,0.8);} But this did not work. So something is still not quite correct here I think.

Comment: Well that's possibly to do with your markup, but from the code you commented, the child theme is definitely being enqueued properly as expected. You could try adding a lower priority to the child theme's `wp_enqueue_scripts` action. I've updated my answer to illustrate.

Comment: Well thank you for all the help, I am new to this as you can tell I am sure. Hope to figure it out soon. Thank you for your time.

Comment: No problem. Since the child theme elements seem to be enqueued as expected, feel free to accept my answer ;)